# how do i pass some controller methods to an auth check in codeigniter/php

Tags: php, codeigniter

i am using ion auth and codeigniter to build a web app, i would like to specifiy some methods of a controller to maybe an array or something that i can perform a authentication function- and some not, there must be an easier way of added a if/else statement to the function

the reason being here is a very quick examplle

```
class employers extends  MY_Controller{

    function __construct (){

        parent::__construct();
    }
    //i want these to be public 

    function index(){}
    function signup(){}

    //i wan these to require a login

    function post_job(){}   
    function edit_job(){}
    function delete_job(){}
```

Answer (score 0):

Segment the pages or controller actions. You want to require authentication for a controller class. Then you can add a __construct method for that controller class that checks the session to see if the user is logged in. See below

```
class employers extends MY_Controller{

    function __construct (){

        parent::__construct();
    }


    function index(){}
    function signup(){}
```

And

```
class employersDashboard extends MY_Controller{

    function __construct ()
    {
        // Add code to check authentication. If they pass redirect them to one of the actions below.
        // If they fail, redirect them to "signup" action in controller "employers" above
        parent::__construct();
    }    

    function post_job(){}   
    function edit_job(){}
    function delete_job(){}
```

Comment: @ChrisMccabe there is a way, but that would make the coding more ugly. This is a more elegant solution.

Comment: @ChrisMccabe additionally, the code is more organized now and extension of the code will make it prettier and eaiser to read :-).

Comment: @ChrisMccabe Your questions aren't tough. :-p Well, this one wasn't anyway.